# pinterest api: cannot find user when adding collaborators

Tags: pinterest

I want to add collaborators to my pinterest api. But when I type the name of my friend's pinterest username i get an error "no user found". I have follow them, do I need to do something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

before you can add a developer or contributor, you must first follow each other. have them follow you too.

Comment: yea both parties, not just one has to follow each other

Comment: actually i still cant select the submit button....do i need to try to access the api from a terminal or something?